# Is it programmatically possible to communicate with Siri via bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, siri

We see people talk on [bluetooth headsets](http://www.simplyheadsets.com.au/jabra-wave-bluetooth-headset.html?gclid=CMj0o5_jg8ECFdgnvQodcSUAUA) all the time. In addition bluetooth is used to [send notifications to devices like watches](https://getpebble.com/).

My question is **Is it programmatically possible to communicate with Siri via bluetooth?**

Comment: Yes, but don't ask me how - my bluetooth headset is capable of talking to Siri, for dialling, asking what the weather's like etc - it initiates Siri just as though I'd held the home button, but listens to the headset rather than built-in mic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some Bluetooth headphones, speakers and hands-free car audio systems have Siri functionality, the Bluetooth device acts as a speaker/mic with action buttons, one commonly found being the Call button.

So, in answer to your question, yes it's possible with the right equipment.

Comment: Cool - I reckon we need a StarTrek-style communicator badge. It looks like it is possible.

Comment: I like that idea @hawkeye.